# Solve $a^x + b^x = c$ for $x$.

Tags: calculus

This is something I came across today (a specific case of this equation), only to realize I don't have the necessary tools to attack this problem.

This is not any kind of homework or research problem or anything like that. I'm genuinely interested how to approach solving this sort of problems. It may be surprisingly simple, but I just don't see it.

Any help would great appreciated.

Comment: This question has been addressed several times on Mathematics. In general it has no closed-form solution. It is equivalent to the "fractional polynomial equation" $t+t^\alpha=c$, where $\alpha=\ln(b)/\ln(a)$, which proves that it may have no solution by radicals.

Comment: Okay, a bit of pity. I was hoping for a clever approach. I'll delete this question in a day or so since it adds nothing for the rest of the community.

Comment: There are a few values of $\alpha$ for which it is solvable. What is your specific case ?

Comment: Well the original question was to solve $6^x - 2^x = 32$. Re-arranging, $3^x - 2^{(5 - x)} = 1$ implies $1 \leq x \leq 5$, so I assumed integer solution and found $x=2$. The solution is probably unique.

Comment: Interestingly, the Diophantine case (all integer numbers) is solved differently. Write $2^x(3^x-1)=2^5$ and the possible solutions can only be among $\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$.

Comment: @darksky, that rearrangement looks *very* fishy...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your original question is to solve
$$6^x - 2^x = 32$$
and since there is no closed-form solution for the general equation, let's focus on the specific case. First you can easily find a solution $x=2$, but what about others?
Let $f(x) = 6^x - 2^x -32 = 2^x\cdot(3^x-1) - 32$. Now you can apply [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) to show that the only solution is $x=2$:

- the function is stricly increasing (its derivative is $f'(x) = 6^x \log (6)-2^x \log (2) = 2^x\cdot(3^x \cdot \log 6 - \log 2) > 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R^+}$
- $f(0) = -32 < 0, f(3) > 0$
- since it's a composition of continuous and differentiable functions, it is continuous and differentiable. Thus the theorem tells us that the only solution is a member of the interval $[0;3]$ so $x=2$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 3):

Just as  Yves Daoust commented, in the most general case, this equation does not show explicit solutions and numerical methods (such as [Newton method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method)) will be required.

This does not make (in principle) any problem if a reasonable estimate can be used for starting iterations.

So, let us consider $$f(x)=a^x+b^x-c$$ the zero of which being looked for. This function can be very stiff and, so, it would be better to consider $$g(x)=\log(a^x+b^x)-\log(c)$$ Let us assume $a >b>1$ and $c>0$; so, the solution would be such that $$\frac{\log (c)-\log (2)}{\log (a)}< x<\frac{\log (c)-\log (2)}{\log (b)}$$ which is already good since we bracketed the solution.

So, let us be lazy and choose the midpoint as $x_0$.

Let us try using $a=\pi$, $b=e$, $c=123456789$. If you look at the plot of function $g(x)$, you should notice that it is very close to  straight line (which is always good).
 Using the above bounds, we already know that $$15.6703<x<17.9383$$ So let us start iterating with Newton methods : it will provide as successive iterates $$x_0=16.8042746089317$$ $$x_1=16.1960353781344$$  $$x_2=16.1957749465687$$ $$x_3=16.1957749465186$$ which is the solution for fifteen significant figures.

Comment: You use this iteration in many problems as i see so how do you do that is it calculator and how did newton did it??

Comment: Please share a link

Comment: @ArchisWelankar. A link to what ? This is just using Newton method. The only trick is to make the transform such that the function be much more linear.

Answer (score 0):

**Considering the equation $a^x+b^x=c$, where $a>b>0$:**

(Not $6^x-2^x=32$ from the comments.)

The derivative of the LHS is

$$f'(x)=\ln(a)a^x+\ln(b)b^x,$$

which has a single root,

$$x'=\log_{a/b}\left(-\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}\right)$$ when $a>1>b$, corresponding to a minimum of $f$, and none otherwise.

If $x'$ exists, the equation has two solutions iff $f(x')<c$; if $x'$ does not exist, it has a single solution iff $c>0$.

An efficient procedure to bracket the solutions is to start from $x=x'$ and try arguments $x\pm s$ where the step increases by doubling, $s=2^{k}$. Very quickly, $f(x\pm 2^k)$ will exceed $c$.

In the monotonic case, the comparison $f(0)=2>c$ tells you the sign of the solution and the direction to step to.

From there, you can use one of the dichotomic or Regula Falsi methods which will guarantee convergence. Newton's iterations may be faster, but guarantees on convergence are much harder to establish (and in case you cross the $x'$ border, you are stuck).

Comment: Numerical methods don't interest me much since we have wolfram alpha for that. But thanks anyways.

Comment: @darksky: the true challenge of equation solving is to make sure to find all the roots, wherever they are. Contrary to common belief, no numerical method can achieve that in all cases, you can't do without calculus.